# How can I efficiently select a text prediction given by Windows' text suggestions feature?

Tags: windows-10, autocomplete, text-editing, input, productivity

I currently select a text prediction given by Windows' text suggestions feature via the mouse, or  with the arrow key followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This is very inefficient. How can I efficiently (= by pressing just 1 key, e.g. <kbd>TAB</kbd> as in Gmail) select a text prediction given by Windows' text suggestions feature?

[image]